# Object Status (Table, View etc.) VALID/INVALID in Informix

Tags: view, informix, status

Does Informix have object status? In Oracle there is a status on the views, tables and other objects represented by VALID/INVALID values.

An equivalent Oracle query is:

```
SELECT owner,
       object_name,
       status
  FROM all_objects
```

What about Informix?

Comment: I don't think there's an equivalent concept.  What does it really indicate in Oracle?

Comment: Thank you for responding Jonathan! In Oracle, when dependencies of an object change impacting the object, that object becomes invalid and needs to be re-validated or recompiled.  That object will still remain in the database, but in invalid state until re-validated or recompiled. Are you certain that Informix does not have that feature? You mentioned "I don't think" ... could someone else please confirm?

Comment: Stored procedures will be automatically recompiled without needing to trouble anyone, so that isn't an issue.  If a dependency for a view vanishes, the view is deleted, AFAIK; if not, the delete of the dependency is 'restricted'. (There could be endless fun in the permissions, and chasing views built on views built on top of views.)  We can debate whether that's better or not; it's different, at any rate.  I'm pretty darn sure that the concept doesn't apply in Informix.

Comment: There's a system view called SYSOBJSTATE. It contains the state for constraints, triggers and indexes.   It doesn't have information about views. The "state" can be enabled, disabled or filtering.... RTFM for more details. I recall seeing a disabled index after using High Performance Loader (HPL) due to lack of space to re-enable it....